# Help with Jacobian

Tags: jacobian, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm muddling my way through Strogatz Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos, and I've run into something I'm too dumb to understand.

In example $6.6.3$, he gives us a system:

$\dot x = 2 \cos x - \cos y$

$\dot y = 2 \cos y - \cos x$

And gives us a Jacobian of (where x* and y* are the critial points and x*=y*)

$\begin{bmatrix} 2\sin x* && \sin x* \\ \sin x* && 2\sin x* \end{bmatrix}$

But when I take the partial derivatives like he shows in section 6.3, I get

$\begin{bmatrix} -2\sin x* && \sin y* \\ \sin x* && -2\sin y* \end{bmatrix}$

I get that he showed x*=y*, but where did the negative signs go?

Apologies again for not being able to figure out the formatting, I'm stuck on mobile due to a dead computer.

Comment: i'll edit for you

Comment: Thank you, Saketh.  I'm new to this and couldn't figure out the dot or how to make matrices.

Comment: @MCA I gave it a shot editing, but I simply didn't know what you were doing in some cases. Is $\dot x$ what you wanted when you wrote xdot?  There are further cases where you put periods and asterisks in and I wasn't sure what you were aiming for.

There are also a few places in the first matrix where it seems $y$'s are missing and there are $x$'s in their place...

Comment: @rschwieb i think i edited it at the same time as you; i wasn't sure about the asterisks either.

Comment: Thanks everyone, that looks much better!  The weird periods were something the editor put in on mobile and wouldn't delete.  The x* and y* is supposed to be for the critical points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the book and it says that the dynamical system is

$\dot x = -2 \cos x - \cos y$

$\dot y = -2 \cos y - \cos x$

Which is not the same that you wrote. What you did it's fine for that dynamical system.

Comment: Thanks, this makes much more sense! I did some digging, and the first printing of the book (purple cover with blue swirly thing) has your equations, but the second printing (still 1st edition) that I'm working off (pink cover with red bar on top) is missing the minus signs, leading to my confusion.